# Retrieve numeric property name from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I received the below json result and am trying to get the 2048 value.
below is the JSON result.

```
{
  "0": "https://media.elomilingerie.com/medias/110x154-pdp-thumb-ES801502-BLK-primary-Elomi-Swim-Tropical-Falls-Black-Underwire-Plunge-Bikini-Top.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHByb2R1Y3RJbWFnZXN8ODEzNXxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGFHWmhMMmhtWmk4NU56STBOek14TlRVMU9EY3dMekV4TUhneE5UUmZjR1J3WDNSb2RXMWlYMFZUT0RBeE5UQXlYMEpNUzE5d2NtbHRZWEo1WDBWc2IyMXBMVk4zYVcwdFZISnZjR2xqWVd3dFJtRnNiSE10UW14aFkyc3RWVzVrWlhKM2FYSmxMVkJzZFc1blpTMUNhV3RwYm1rdFZHOXdMbXB3Wnd8MjZkNTRlMWY1YWM4OWY2MTNkNDYxM2Q5NDdkZDk4NjYwY2M5NWYzN2ZmZDYzNmI3MTc5NTlkMzM4YTg5NmI5Yg",
  "640": "https://media.elomilingerie.com/medias/480x672-pdp-mobile-ES801502-BLK-primary-Elomi-Swim-Tropical-Falls-Black-Underwire-Plunge-Bikini-Top.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHByb2R1Y3RJbWFnZXN8ODMxMDZ8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xhRGMyTDJoaE15ODVOekkwTnpNMU5ESXlORGswTHpRNE1IZzJOekpmY0dSd1gyMXZZbWxzWlY5RlV6Z3dNVFV3TWw5Q1RFdGZjSEpwYldGeWVWOUZiRzl0YVMxVGQybHRMVlJ5YjNCcFkyRnNMVVpoYkd4ekxVSnNZV05yTFZWdVpHVnlkMmx5WlMxUWJIVnVaMlV0UW1scmFXNXBMVlJ2Y0M1cWNHY3w1YjQyODRhY2Q5YTJmY2U4NDA4MDNjZTUzNzM4ZjViNWRmYTlkYjQxZmQxM2ZiOTExNTZjYWM3N2FkNGNmZWU4",
  "1024": "https://media.elomilingerie.com/medias/768x1075-pdp-tablet-ES801502-BLK-primary-Elomi-Swim-Tropical-Falls-Black-Underwire-Plunge-Bikini-Top.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHByb2R1Y3RJbWFnZXN8MTg2Mzc5fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8YURGaUwyZzBPQzg1TnpJME56TTBPRGs0TWpBMkx6YzJPSGd4TURjMVgzQmtjRjkwWVdKc1pYUmZSVk00TURFMU1ESmZRa3hMWDNCeWFXMWhjbmxmUld4dmJXa3RVM2RwYlMxVWNtOXdhV05oYkMxR1lXeHNjeTFDYkdGamF5MVZibVJsY25kcGNtVXRVR3gxYm1kbExVSnBhMmx1YVMxVWIzQXVhbkJufDMwNWE5YjI0OWYxYjFkNmFjOTM1YjdkNWI3YjBiZjdjZjNhYzViNDkwNGZmMjcxMmIzZmQ5MjgxNzkyY2Y0NzU",
  "1400": "https://media.elomilingerie.com/medias/992x1389-pdp-desktop-ES801502-BLK-primary-Elomi-Swim-Tropical-Falls-Black-Underwire-Plunge-Bikini-Top.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHByb2R1Y3RJbWFnZXN8MjgyMDYyfGltYWdlL2pwZWd8YURObEwyZ3lZeTg1TnpJME56TTBNRFEyTWpNNEx6azVNbmd4TXpnNVgzQmtjRjlrWlhOcmRHOXdYMFZUT0RBeE5UQXlYMEpNUzE5d2NtbHRZWEo1WDBWc2IyMXBMVk4zYVcwdFZISnZjR2xqWVd3dFJtRnNiSE10UW14aFkyc3RWVzVrWlhKM2FYSmxMVkJzZFc1blpTMUNhV3RwYm1rdFZHOXdMbXB3Wnd8MGM1ODRiZGRhZDVmYzBmZDUzZThjMDI1ZmM0MGMwMzU4NjUxMzRmZDM0MTk1MmFmMmQ2MTVlZjc4MjUxNWJlMA",
  "2048": "https://media.elomilingerie.com/medias/1200x1680-pdp-widescreen-ES801502-BLK-primary-Elomi-Swim-Tropical-Falls-Black-Underwire-Plunge-Bikini-Top.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHByb2R1Y3RJbWFnZXN8Mzc4MzgzfGltYWdlL2pwZWd8YURrekwyZzRaaTg1TnpJME56TXlOek0xTlRFNEx6RXlNREI0TVRZNE1GOXdaSEJmZDJsa1pYTmpjbVZsYmw5RlV6Z3dNVFV3TWw5Q1RFdGZjSEpwYldGeWVWOUZiRzl0YVMxVGQybHRMVlJ5YjNCcFkyRnNMVVpoYkd4ekxVSnNZV05yTFZWdVpHVnlkMmx5WlMxUWJIVnVaMlV0UW1scmFXNXBMVlJ2Y0M1cWNHY3wxMTI4MjJkZGFkOGUwMDA4NzFkZDhlZjA4YTBjOTU2ZDI5NWIyZWMzZWY5ZDhjZmQwY2YzNTg3ZGVmNWFkNjk5"
}
```

I have received the JSON results.
I am trying to reach the value of 2048.

I know if string name we can a take variable and we can Access via name but above key contains numeric Key.

Comment: Note that nothing about this is JSON - I have edited the question to reflecthis. The data structure you've got is an object - which is perhaps why you were not able to research a solution that worked. See the duplicate for the answer to your issue.

Comment: Solution in question. `const myURI = obj["1024"];` Closing this question because seems like did not even tried to research a solution. Which is basic manipulation of Object literals, JSON , JSON parsing etc.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the solution is only in the question because you edited it to be there...?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Please never add solutions into the question themselves. Solutions belong in answers. If you cannot find a suitable duplicate, then please let the question receive proper answers.